# Where can i get sample Oracle Apex demo project on leave management system?

Tags: oracle-apex

I have to prepare a dummy leave management system in oracle apex. Can you please help out with it? Or suggest websites where i could find information?

Answer (score 0):

As a start point, you can familiarize yourself with APEX by reviewing the [App  Gallery](https://apex.oracle.com/en/solutions/apps/).

Also, you can take a look at the [Commercial Apps](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/apex_pm/r/apex-community/applications).